# Why does Opera's console give the current date for javascript:alert(document.lastModified)?

Tags: opera

On every website I go on, the console returns the current date. I did it in Chrome, and it worked just fine.

Comment: works fine on opera 29.0 on mac

Comment: @Kaiido that might be the problem, I'm using 27.0

Comment: Good news: I can confirm it outputs the current date on Opera 28 on Win 7. Bad news: I get the exact same thing on Chrome 42 and on Vivaldi 1.0.162. In other words, it's not specific to Opera, it's a Blink issue. If @Kaiido doesn't get this on Mac, maybe it's specific to Blink on Windows.

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter, just tried on win7 and can't repro either… can you try on this page : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/lastModified ?  I know that on SO it will be the current date, probably because the page is generated dynamically, but on the page in the link, it returns `02/21/2015 19:04:19`

Comment: @Kaiido: Strange, you're right - confirmed with all three Blink browsers. But, going back to try it on this page, even several minutes after I refreshed the page, it always gives me the _current timestamp_. Perhaps it checks some header and returns the current date when the page says it's dynamically generated. The page you linked to says there's an existing Webkit bug that uses UTC instead of local time, yet I get `02/21/2015 18:04:19` on that page rather than `19:04`. Smells buggy!

Comment: Yep don't know either why does SO return always the current Time, maybe because it checks for new comments and notifications every seconds or so.